# uploaded/changed files in aws beanstalk php app

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have some question. I deployed an PHP app (online shop) on AWS beanstalk - working fine.

But how is it possible to save changed content like uploaded files (eg. product pictures) or a modified shop config. I did not find any information if this is possible.

Because if not, by deploying next version or autoscaling all changes/pictures are lost.

Regards

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing the uploaded files and content? From your question it seems like you are storing it on the instance itself. This is not reliable and the instance can be replaced at any time. I would recommend storing it in a more durable store like AWS S3 or an RDS instance or a dynamo db table.

Comment: `From your question it seems like you are storing it on the instance itself.`
yes, but it´s not a good idea, i know ;-)

is it possible to mount a s3 bucket/drive in an beanstalk application/instance?

Comment: I would recommend accessing S3 using the AWS SDKs in a language you prefer. https://aws.amazon.com/tools/

You can also use 'awscli': https://aws.amazon.com/cli/, but using SDKs is better if you are writing a service.
You can refer the S3 Getting Started guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/GetStartedWithS3.html

There is some discussion on AWS forums on how to mount an S3 bucket to an EC2 instance but I have not used it personally, so you would have to test if that solution works for you:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=475840

Comment: i also think this is the correct way, thank you. found an integration for S3 to beanstalk: https://github.com/nathanlenz/s3fs-on-aws-beanstalk

Comment: Great let me know how it goes. I am curious.